# Naming one dimension of an array

Tags: arrays, r, rename

```
a=array(data=1:8, dim=c(2,2,2), dimnames=NULL)
```

How can I modify the names of this array (after it has been constructed) and name only the third dimension (the layer when printed) of this array?

I tried

```
a = array(a, dimnames=list(NULL, NULL, c('a','b')))
names(a) = list(NULL, NULL, c('a','b'))
```

but it doesn't work. What is the solution?

Thank you

Comment: did you try a.dimnames<-list(NULL, NULL, 'aName') or dimnames(a)<-list(NULL, NULL, 'aName')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- array(data=1:8, dim=c(2,2,2), dimnames=NULL)
dimnames(x) <- list(NULL, NULL, c("a", "b"))

# , , a
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# , , b
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    7
# [2,]    6    8
```

Comment: Oh…I was close! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Two other approaches:

```
dimnames(a)[3] <- list(c('a', 'b'))
```

and

```
dimnames(a)[[3]] <- c('a','b')
```